# Curl to download CSV from Spotify Insights?

Tags: php, csv, curl, libcurl, spotify

Trying to download a CSV from Spotify Fan Insights that works fine in a browser setting:

```
https://artists.spotify.com/api/data/v1/artist/<URI>/timeline.csv
```

However, any attempt at using cURL to grab this data comes back with no result. I know the URL needs an authentication token, which I am passing, but still no result. I've tried passing cookie data, all types of headers, and a combination of everything in between.

```
$agent= 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';
$path = "/tmp/spot_test.csv";
$fp = fopen($path, 'w+');
$cookie_file_path = "../../../../private/tmp/cookie.txt";

$ch=curl_init();
$url = "https://artists.spotify.com/api/data/v1/artist/<URI>/timeline.csv";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,100);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);

$auth_header = "Authorization: Bearer ". $accessToken;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($auth_header,'Content-type: application/csv','Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=spot_test.csv','Pragma: no-cache','Expires: 0'));

$resp = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if (empty($resp)){

echo "Nothing returned from url.<br />";

} else {

echo $resp;

}
```

Returns an empty file & "1" on the page. Any thoughts?

Comment: Set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to true?

Comment: Tried that. It was in there originally in place of writing to file with `fopen` & `CURLOPT_FILE`. With `RETURNTRANSFER` code returns `Nothing returned from url.`